# Transforming into class based-view, how and why?

Tags: django

It seems like most people use class based view rather than just boring functions. I learnt django through free online tutorials, and they don't really tell me about class based view(at least the ones I did). 
I would be really grateful if anyone can show me how my functions can be turned into class-based view. And why they are superior to the functions. I'm pretty comfortable with functions but unfortunately most examples I want to understand are in class-based view. Here are my codes.

```
def index(request):

    categories = Category.objects.order_by('likes')[:5]
    latest_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    popular_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-views')
    hot_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-score')[:25]

    context_dict = {
        'latest_posts': latest_posts,
        'popular_posts': popular_posts,
        'hot_posts': hot_posts,
        'categories': categories
    }
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context_dict)
#for single-post page
#we use uuslug 
def post(request, slug):
    single_post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    single_post.views += 1  # increment the number of views
    single_post.save()      # and save it
    context_dict = {
      'single_post' :single_post,
    }

    return render(request, 'main/post.html', context_dict)
#for category page
#we use slugfield this time 
def category(request, category_name_slug):
  context_dict = {}
  try:
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
    context_dict['category_name'] = category.name

    posts = Post.objects.filter(category=category)
    context_dict['posts'] = posts
    context_dict['category'] = category
  except Category.DoesNotExist:
    pass

  return render(request, 'main/category.html', context_dict)
#for adding category

def add_category(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CategoryForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save(commit=True)
      return index(request)
    else:
      print form.errors
  else:
    form = CategoryForm()

  return render(request, 'main/add_category.html', {'form':form})
```

my attempt to add_category

```
class categoryCreateView(CreateView):

   model = Category
   form_class = CategoryForm
   template_name = 'main/add_category.html'

   def form_valid(self, form):
      self.object = form.save(commit=False)
      # any manual settings go here
      self.object.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('category', args=[self.object.slug]))

   @method_decorator(login_required)
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      return super(categoryCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

EDIT::

```
class CategoryFormView(FormView):
    form_class = CategoryForm
    template_name = 'main/add_category.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('category', args=[self.object.slug]))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add any extra context data needed for form here.
        return context

@method_decorator(login_required)
       def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          return super(categoryCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
from main import views
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from views import *

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    #url(r'^add_post/', views.add_post, name='add_post'),
    url(r'^add_post/$', login_required(CategoryFormView.as_view(), name='post-add'),

    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/edit/$', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-edit'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/delete/$', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),


    url(r'^add_category/', CategoryFormView.as_view, name='add_category'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w|\-]+)/$', views.post, name='post'),

    url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
    ]
```

Comment: Is there something in the documentation that you didn't understand? What is the issue you're facing? Did you try creating a CBV? Look out for [`TemplateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView)

Comment: Hello yes I looked into the documentation and I got confused, so I looked into http://www.onespacemedia.com/news/2014/feb/5/getting-started-generic-class-based-views-django/ but still get errors whenever I try

Comment: Can you post your code here? What you tried. Including what the errors you're getting?

Comment: I get invalid syntax, thought it might be because of indentation so tried bunch of times but errors. Also I'm not sure how to do for listview and detail-view because they have more in context_dict

Comment: You can extend `FormView` instead of `CreateView`. Set the `success_url` for form valid. Override `get_context_data(self, **kwargs)` to pass context data.

Comment: ok I will try it then, do you have any guidance for index,post,category functions??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `CreateView`, just create a `FormView`:

```
class CategoryFormView(FormView):
    form_class = CategoryForm
    template_name = 'main/add_category.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('category', args=[self.object.slug]))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add any extra context data needed for form here.
        return context
```

Comment: the main problem was 
   @method_decorator(login_required)
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      return super(categoryCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
this part was getting invalid syntax

Comment: @stackchange That should work. What exactly is the error message? Did you confirm there is no indentation error? How about trying adding the decorator to `urls.py` file?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure I set my url right, please look at the above that's what I have put

Comment: @stackchange No I mean, instead of using decorator, try wrapping the urls - `login_required(CategoryFormView.as_view())` in urls.py file.

Comment: it still gives me same error:as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: pretty sure that's a wrong answer/ using login required function in url gives me invalid syntax (urls.py, line 21)

Comment: @stackchange You didn't close the `login_required` function parenthesis after `as_view()`.